# Issues installing mplcusrsors

Tags: python, mplcursors

I am trying to isntall mplcursors. I use the cmd: pip install mplcursors.
however I got the below message. I am not sure why it mentioned python2.7 coz I am sure my I have python3.6 in place.
[image]

Comment: `mplcursors` is not available for `python 2.7`. Check the documentation or tags for appropriate versions.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `pip3 install mplcursors`, because you might have Python 2.7 and 3.6